# Why do Genesis 1 and 2 sequences of events and other details differ so widely?

Tags: genesis, creation

In Genesis 1 the seed-plants are made first. Then birds, aquatic and marine creatures are summoned from the ***water***. Beasts of the ***earth*** are called forth from the ***earth***. Man is ***shaped*** (SHAPE(V): (ברא / b.r.a) To fashion or form. Strong's: #1254) in God's image, both male and female together as the cherry on top of creation, then sent out to multiply, with "every herb bearing seed, which is upon the face of all the earth, and every tree, in the which is the fruit of a tree yielding seed" as food.

In Genesis 2 "every plant of the field before it was in the earth, and every herb of the field before it grew" (in seed trays and pots?) come first. Man is molded (MOLD(V): (יצר / y.ts.r) To give shape to; to press or squeeze, as when pressing clay into a shape to form a vessel. Alternate Translations: distress. Strong's: #3334, #3335) from dust, as are birds and animals. Woman is ***built*** (BUILD(V): (בנה / b.n.h) To construct a building or home with wood, stone or other material or a family with sons. Strong's: #1129) from a piece of Adam.
God gives no reason for creating man in His own image, but Adam is shaped for a ***very specific purpose***. Gen. 2:5 "...there was not a man to till the ground..." and Gen.2:15: "...And the LORD God took the man, and put him into the garden of Eden to dress it and to keep it..."

The animals and birds are molded ***after*** the man, ostensibly to provide him with a "suitable companion", but when this idea fails, God makes a female version of the man and hands it to him.
That is enough for now as there is a great deal more. How are these vast disparities to be explained?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Questions need to be respectful of those with different opinions and interpretations.

Comment: I've removed your requestion to not quote other people, because that's not how this site works. Answers need to provide supporting evidence for their claims and interpretations. You don't have to accept the supporting evidence people provide, but if we restrict from the beginning what kinds of supporting evidence are allowed then very few questions could be adequately answered. You yourself quote from Strongs, imagine if you couldn't do that! Please see this meta discussion: [Where does external evidence fit on a hermeneutics site?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3774/2757)

Comment: I do not see "*vast disparities*" between the creation accounts in Gen 1 and 2.  Indeed, I see no disparities at all.  Gen 2 is simply an expansion of the description of what happened in Day #6 of creation week (of Gen 1). Gen 2:19, 20 is simply a flash-back to the previous day's activities (the Hebrew verbs do not have tense as English verbs do, but this is another matter).

Comment: Scripture states that God made humanity and he made humanity 'male and female'. It is incorrect to say that the woman is a 'female version of the man' : incorrect grammatically and semantically, but also spiritually, since man and woman set forth Christ and the Body of Christ, the Church.

Comment: The major difference in the two accounts of Creation in the opening chapters of Genesis is the referencing of God as _Elohim_ in the first account and _Jehovah_ in the second. This is the main way in which the whole (twin) account may be understood : there are two revelations, demonstrating two aspects of creation. The natural creation and the first humanity. The new creation and another humanity. All the other differences fall into line with this major difference.

Answer (score 1):

Some people believe that the two stories in Genesis fit well together. Myself being one of them. Let me explain: Genesis 1 talks about the creation of the world and humanities role. Genesis 2 looks more closely at the sixth day and how the Garden of Eden came to be. In this case, the stories are not at odds but each one looks at different things. If their focus is different it only makes sense that there will be some disparities, in the sense that they lack certain similarities simply *because* their focus is different.

Now, there are two primary "claims" of Genesis 1 and 2 being contradictory.

1. In regard to plant life.
2. In regard to animal life.

**First, let me give a quick [summary](https://www.gotquestions.org/two-Creation-accounts.html) in regards to plant life:**

- Genesis 1:11 mentions vegetation created on the third day.
- Genesis 2:5 notes no plant life before man, attributed to no rain and no one to cultivate the land.
- No contradiction as Genesis 2:5 likely refers to the period before the third day.
- Genesis 2:6-7 covers several days, with man created on the sixth day.
- Genesis 2:9 focuses on the specific growth of trees in Eden, post-creation of vegetation.
- **Conclusion:** No contradiction between Genesis 1:11 and Genesis 2:5,9; the texts refer to different times and contexts.

**Second, let me give a quick [summary](https://www.gotquestions.org/two-Creation-accounts.html) in regards to animal life:**

- The perceived contradiction involves the timing of animal creation relative to humans in Genesis 1:24-25 vs. Genesis 2:19.
- Some translations of Genesis 2:19 suggest animals were created after humans which would cause a contradiction.
- A plausible interpretation of Genesis 2:19-20 indicates animals were created before humans.
- The text does imply God had already created animals before introducing them to man for naming.
- **Conclusion:** No contradiction exists; animals were created first, followed by humans, who then named the animals.